# Processing FreeBSD's PF logs with tcpdump/sed/awk

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk, tcpdump, pf

I'm running FreeBSD and have PF firewall set up and this is command i use to display daily number of firewall hits (blocked traffic)

```
sudo tcpdump -n -e -tttt -r /var/log/pflog | grep $(date +%Y-%m-%d)|wc -l|sed 's/ *//' >> /home/pentago/www/pf.txt
```

That displays number, say 95.

I want to process pf.txt file in a way that each line has the date before hit count.

For example:

- 01-01-2014 - 95
- 02-01-2014 - 98
- 03-01-2014 - 113
- 04-01-2014 - 92

etc..

Simply put, I need sed/awk to prepend the date to each new line of the file.
Does that sound reasonable?

Comment: I guess 'I want to..' is pretty much self explanatory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DATE=$(date +%Y-%m-%d)
HITS=$(sudo tcpdump -n -e -tttt -r /var/log/pflog | grep -c $DATE)
echo "$DATE - $HITS" >> /home/pentago/www/pf.txt
```

Comment: Great, i modified it a little bit to include the date command and delete some whitespace with sed:

`DATE=$(date +%Y-%m-%d); HITS=$(sudo tcpdump -n -e -tttt -r /var/log/pflog | grep $DATE | wc -l | sed 's/ *//'); echo "$DATE - $HITS"`

Comment: @purpler To count matching lines, just use `grep -c` instead of piping `grep` to `wc` and cleaning up the whitespace.

Comment: You're right, it's far more convenient instead of using wc and sed. I've learned something new today. Thanks a ton!

Comment: @Gilles Very true. I just haven't managed to fix my finger macros yet...